# Why some issues are not listed (skipped) in online list of journals?

Tags: journals, online-publication, online-resource

I want to know where I can find the articles published in "[Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/crll/crll-overview.xml?tab_body=toc-68871)" Volume 2013: **Issues 675-682**? These issues seem to be missing.

Comment: Contact the journal directly.

Comment: are you sure that these are issues? This looks more like page numbers.

Comment: @MaartenBuis: Yes, if you look at the website, this journal numbers its issues sequentially across volumes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the publisher's website.  I would suggest contacting them directly to report it.  There seems to be a similar problem with the issues from 2012 and 2011, though not other years.

If you have a subscription to MathSciNet, you can see [a list of all issues of the journal](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/issues.html?groupid=2764&r=1&extend=1), including those, and click for a list of articles in those issues.  Unfortunately the DOI links for those papers seem to be broken as well ([example](https://mathscinet.ams.org/leavingmsn?url=https://doi.org/10.1515/crelle.2011.185)), which also supports the hypothesis that this is a website bug, as DOIs are supposed to be permanently accessible.

If you're at a university, you might see if your library has those volumes on paper.  If not, and you need a specific paper, they may be able to get a scan from another university that does have it, via the interlibrary loan system.  Talk to your friendly university librarian; they'll know how to help.